# Does anyone know the In Circuit Programming algorithm for the Philips P89LPC901 microcontroller

Tags: 8051

I am looking for the ICP / In Circuit Programming algorithm for the P89LPC901 microcontroller.  Not the IAP / In Application Programming algorithm.  I see Flash Magic sells some devices for programming, however, I wish to design/build my own.

Yes - I see it's a bit old.

Comment: Chapter 14 of the P89LPC901 User's Manual describes the flash program memory and how to use it.  https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM_P89LPC901_902_903.pdf

Comment: Thanks Tim.   I saw that.  It does not describe the serial protocol used with ICP specifically.

Comment: What serial protocol?  There aren't enough pins to do JTAG, SPI, or I2S.

Comment: The ICP serial programming protocol.  I have not verified if it is the EXACT same, but it appears to be like i2c.  

I see no reason why the device could not do SPI ... which requires 4 pins - though that IS NOT what the ICP protocol uses.

Answer (score 1):

A quick web research revealed [this specification](https://www.teamfdi.com/wp-content/uploads/ICP_LPC9xx_v24.pdf). However, a broader web search did not reveal an official source of this document.

Unfortunately the protocol is too complex to fit in an actual answer here.